# How do I get a real file url in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, redirect, python-requests

I have an url http://www.vbb.de/de/datei/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip which "redirects" me to http://images.vbb.de/assets/ftp/file/286316.zip. Redirect in quotes because python says there is no redirect:

```
    In [51]: response = requests.get('http://www.vbb.de/de/datei/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip')
        ...: if response.history:
        ...:     print "Request was redirected"
        ...:     for resp in response.history:
        ...:         print resp.status_code, resp.url
        ...:     print "Final destination:"
        ...:     print response.status_code, response.url
        ...: else:
        ...:     print "Request was not redirected"
        ...:     
    Request was not redirected
```

Status Code is also 200.  `response.history` gives nothing. `response.url` gives the first url and not the real one. But it's possible to get the real url in firefox -> developer tools -> network. How do I make in python 2.7? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't see any redirect in that request.  I get a `200` response code (a redirect would return a `301` or `302` response code with a `Location` header).

Comment: @larsks, yeah, thet's even the problem. I could easily get the url if there was a redirect.

Comment: So I guess I don't understand your question.  `requests` is just an http module.  It doesn't parse the content at all.  If the redirect is happening due to content in the document (`meta` tags, javascript), you would need to handle the returned content yourself.

Comment: @larsks, the question is how do I get the real url: http://images.vbb.de/assets/ftp/file/286316.zip

Comment: The real question is what does the server return so that Firefox fetches that, and how can you do that in your code. Your question doesn't contain enough details to help us help you figure that out. Maybe some brave soul wants to do the digging but it really should be included in your question from the start.

Comment: I see a `301 Moved Permanently` when using Firefox / Network.

Comment: Dmitri, as I said, the redirect is happening due to document content (in this case, the `meta http-equiv="refresh"` tag in the `<head>` element). You would need to parse that out yourself if you want it.

Comment: @Martin Evans, but why does `response = requests.get('http://www.vbb.de/de/datei/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip')` delivers me the 200 code and therefore an empty `response.history`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first carry out the redirect manually by parsing the new `window.location.href` from the first returned HTML. This then creates a `301` reply with the name of the target file contained inside the `Location` header that is returned:

```
import requests
import re
import os

base_url = 'http://www.vbb.de'
response = requests.get(base_url + '/de/datei/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip')
manual_redirect = base_url + re.findall('window.location.href\s+=\s+"(.*?)"', response.text)[0]
response = requests.get(manual_redirect, stream=True)
target_filename = response.history[0].headers['Location'].split('/')[-1]

print "Downloading: '{}'".format(target_filename)
with open(target_filename, 'wb') as f_zip:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        f_zip.write(chunk)
```

This would display:

```
Downloading: '286316.zip'
```

and result in a 29,464,299 byte zip file being created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup to read the meta tag in the header of the HTML page and get the redirect URL e.g.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> a = requests.get("http://www.vbb.de/de/datei/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip")
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'http-equiv': lambda x:x.lower() == 'refresh'})[0]['content'].split('URL=')[1]
'/de/download/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip'
```

This URL would be relative to the original URL's domain, making the new URL `http://www.vbb.de/de/download/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip`. Downloading this appears to download the ZIP file for me:

```
>>> a = requests.get("http://www.vbb.de/de/download/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip", stream=True)
>>> with open('test.zip', 'wb') as f:
...     a.raw.decode_content = True
...     shutil.copyfileobj(a.raw, f)
...
```

---

```
 $ unzip -l test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
     5554  2015-11-20 15:17   agency.txt
  2151517  2015-11-20 15:17   calendar_dates.txt
    71731  2015-11-20 15:17   calendar.txt
    65424  2015-11-20 15:17   routes.txt
   816498  2015-11-20 15:17   stops.txt
196020096  2015-11-20 15:17   stop_times.txt
   365499  2015-11-20 15:17   transfers.txt
 11765292  2015-11-20 15:17   trips.txt
      113  2015-11-20 15:17   logging
---------                     -------
211261724                     9 files
```

It is on this redirect that there is a 301 status returned:

```
>>> a.history
[<Response [301]>]
>>> a
<Response [200]>
>>> a.history[0]
<Response [301]>
>>> a.history[0].url
'http://www.vbb.de/de/download/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip'
>>> a.url
'http://images.vbb.de/assets/ftp/file/286316.zip'
```

Comment: this is again the starting link, and just parsing doesn't give me  the output link, because it's not in the source code of [link](http://www.vbb.de/de/datei/GTFS_VBB_Nov2015_Dez2016.zip). I need somehow to retrieve the outcome link [link](http://images.vbb.de/assets/ftp/file/286316.zip) from the server response

Comment: @Dmitri - as I show in the additional part, you can indeed download the file with the link obtained - is this not sufficient for your purposes? Surely your objective is to download the file?

Comment: @Dmitri after the manual redirection, a 301 status is returned and you are redirected to the real location of the file - see my last addition to my answer

Comment: unfortunately, that's not enough, I really need the second link

Comment: @Dmitri see previous comment & addition to answer

Comment: thats perfect! Thank you! Now I did get what `a.raw.decode_content` was for.