# How can I get href links from HTML and download files using Python?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

How can I parse all links in html, which contain link to *.rar file and download all these files?

There are 3 links from html which I need to parse:

```
<a class="zlink" href="http://example.com/lv/20180530/L10.rar">
<a class="zlink" href="http://example.com/est/20180530/ES10.rar">
<a class="zlink" href="http://example.com/pol/20180530/PL10.rar">
```

Html consists  to another file type, like favicon or hmtl.

```
import requests
import urllib
import random
import threading
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

user_agent_list = [
    #Windows
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
    #Linux
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
]
url = 'http://example.com'

#Using Requests 
# establishing session
s = requests.session() 
user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
headers = {
    'login_username': 'user',
    'login_password': 'pass',
    'User-Agent': user_agent}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response.content)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("$rar")})
    r = requests.get('href')
```

Comment: So what doesn't work with your code ?

Comment: I don't know how to save all rar-files from links and there is some parsing errors in cycle

Comment: 1/ just like you would save any other content from an HTTP response: write the response body to a file. 2/ Are we supposed to guess what errors you have ? Please post a MCVE.

Comment: This answer should help you: [Get filename and download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48229071/4985733)

Comment: Please show a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code doesn't even compile. And has some unused stuff like two modules, the `Session` object and the `link` in the loop (and also `r`). Why are you using BeautifulSoup <4?